# How to make my app use a zoomed iPhone 6 resolution when using an iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm making my app work on the new iPhones 6/6+. Until now everything worked in zoomed compatibility mode, but I wanted to make some modifications for iPhone 6. Instead of migrating all my assets to @x3, I prefer that my iPhone 6+ version will still be in compatibility mode - but instead of using the old iPhone 5 version, it should use the new iPhone 6 version.

I inserted a splash scree image to iPhone 6, but can't get the iPhone 6+ to run in compatibility mode now:

- Leaving it blank does not show a splash screen at all, and the iPhone 6+ still uses its own resolution.
- Putting the iPhone 6 splash in the iPhone 6+ splash slot, also doesn't show a splash screen, and the iPhone 6+ still uses it own resolution as well.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Probably this is not possible in any automatic way. However you could try detecting iPhone 6 Plus and applying some CGAffineTransformScale to the UIWindow.

Comment: this won't work properly with Autolayout.